# How do I set up a model validation test on update only if association exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4.1, updatemodel

How do I set up a test that checks validations only on update if the model has an association? Below are the 2 classes and the test.

```
user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :survey
    validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :update, if: :survey_completed?

    private
    def survey_completed?
        survey.present?
    end
end

survey.rb
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user, presence: true
end


user_spec.rb
describe "if survey is completed" do
  let(:user) {User.create(email: 'test@test.com')}
  let(:survey) {Survey.create(user_id: user.id)}

  it "returns error if phone number has not been completed" do   
    user.first_name = 'test'
    expect(user.reload.valid?).to be false
  end
end
```

The above test fails, it returns true.  Having looked in the console, I can see that the test is failing because there is no survey for my user, so the validations aren't being run.

I've tried variations with `save!`, using reload, and not using reload and the test always returns true. How do I set up the test so that there is a survey associated with the user?

For simplicity, I've only shown the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rspec `let` is lazy. It isn't evaluated until you use the variable in your code. Since your test does not have `survey` in it, the line `let(:survey) {Survey.create(user_id: user.id)}` is never run.

For this test, I would explicitly create a survey on `user` (i.e. `user.survey.create`) so the validation will run properly.

Comment: Of course, thank you! I used a before block e.g. before(:each) Survey.create(user_id: @user.id). I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough points :(